# How do I enable rich text editing on all my long text fields?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I have a node with 3 long text fields and I want to make rich text editing available on them all. So far all my experiments with Wysiwyg have only resulted in one of the long text fields getting an editor. So what editor/configuration will give me rich text editors on them all?

Comment: I have used CCK Editor before, and it had one option to include paths for which text ares need rich UI editor, so adding `node/*` would enable on all content types. Try checking for Wildcard options in this editor settings.

Comment: @2-Stroker Where is this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now they are all working. I think what happened is that since I have posted the question I have rebooted Apache and MySQL (as well as I may have cleared a cache or two) and that fixed the problem. I've tested a few editors, and now they all seem to work across multiple text areas.